# Is there a python solution for the Comma Sprinkler problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to solve this problem online and would really appreciate it if some could help me:

> **DESCRIPTION:**
>
> Rules for adding commas to an existing piece of text are as follows:
>
> 1.) If a word anywhere in the text is preceded by a comma, find all occurrences of that word in the text, and put a comma before each of
> those occurrences, except in the case where such an occurrence is the
> first word of a sentence or already preceded by a comma.
>
> 2.) If a word anywhere in the text is succeeded by a comma, find all occurrences of that word in the text, and put a comma after each of
> those occurrences, except in the case where such an occurrence is the
> last word of a sentence or already succeeded by a comma.
>
> 3.) Apply rules 1 and 2 repeatedly until no new commas can be added using either of them.
>
> **As an example, consider the text:**
>
> ***"please sit spot. sit spot, sit. spot here now here."***
>
> Because there is a comma after spot in the second sentence, a comma
> should be added after spot in the third sentence as well(but not the
> first sentence, since it is the last word of that sentence).
>
> Also, because there is a comma before the word sit in the second
> sentence, one should be added before that word in the first
> sentence(but no comma is added before the word sit beginning the
> second sentence because it is the first word of that sentence).
>
> Finally, notice that once a comma is added after spot in the third
> sentence, there exists a comma before the first occurrence of the word
> here.
>
> Therefore, a comma is also added before the other occurrence of the
> word here. There are no more commas to be added so the final result
> is:
>
> ***"please, sit spot. sit spot, sit. spot, here now, here."***
>
> **Input**
>
> The input contains one line of text. Each character is either a
> lowercase letter, a comma, a period, or a space.
>
> And:
>
> The text begins with a word.
>
> Between every two words in the text, there is either a single space,
> a comma followed by a space, or a period followed by a space
> (denoting the end of a sentence and the beginning of a new one).
> The last word of the text is followed by a period with no trailing
> space.
>
> **Sample**
>
> ***Input:***  one, two. one tree. four tree. four four. five four. six five.
>
> ***Output***: one, two. one, tree. four, tree. four, four. five, four. six five.

**CODE SO FAR**

I have two functions that handle the cases for the previous word and the next word. I am having some trouble actually calling these functions.

```
comma_list = [] # List to store boolean values if we have a comma
period_list = []  # List to store boolean values if we have  period
text = [] # List of words in the sentence
position = defaultdict(list) # mapping between word and its positions

def do_prev(word):
    done = set()
    if word in done:
        return
    done.add(word)
    for i in position:
        if i == 0 or period_list[i-1] or comma_list[i-1]:
            continue
        comma_list[i-1] = True
        do_next(text[i-1])

def do_next(word):
    done = set()
    if word in done:
        return
    for i in position:
        if period_list[i] or comma_list[i]:
            continue
        comma_list[i] = True
        if ( i+1 < len(text)):
            do_prev(text[i-1]

for word in sentence.split(" "):
    if word.endswith(','):
        comma_list.append(True)
    if word.endswith('.'):
        period_list.append(True)
    
    if comma_list[:-1] or period_list[:-1]:
        word = word[0:len(word) - 1]
    position[word].append(len(text))
    text.append(word)

for i in range(len(text)):
    if comma_list[i]:
        do_next(text[i])
    if i+1 < len(text):
        do_prev(text[i+1])
```

This gives a list index out of range in the do_prev method and I am confused about this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?  Otherwise, this is just asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this using regular expressions. Is that the kind of help you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, Of course, I will paste what I have so far.

Comment: @DanielWalker I have edited the post to reflect my code. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

You have to step back one moment and ask what you are trying to accomplish. Here's how you could look at that problem:

1. Identify which words matches rule 1
2. Identify which words matches rule 2
3. Modify the input sample to add commas at appropriate places
4. Return to step 1 to check if there are still some modifications to do

Here's a way to code this:

```py
input_lines = (
    "please sit spot. sit spot, sit. spot here now here.",
    "one, two. one tree. four tree. four four. five four. six five."
)

def each_word_and_its_follower(input_line):
    input_line = iter(input_line)
    current_word = next(input_line)
    for next_word in input_line:
        yield (current_word, next_word)
        current_word = next_word
    yield (current_word, '')

for input_line in input_lines:
    previous_input = ''
    current_input = input_line
    while (previous_input != current_input):

        previous_input = current_input
        splitted_input = current_input.split()

        rule_1_words = set(
            follower.rstrip(',.') 
            for (current_word, follower) in each_word_and_its_follower(splitted_input) 
            if current_word.endswith(',')
        )
        
        rule_2_words = set(
            current_word.rstrip(',.') 
            for current_word in splitted_input 
            if current_word.endswith(',')
        )

        def modify_words(previous_line):
            for (current_word, follower) in each_word_and_its_follower(previous_line):
                if current_word.endswith('.'):
                    yield current_word
                else:
                    if (follower.rstrip(',.') in rule_1_words) or (current_word.rstrip(',.') in rule_2_words):
                        yield f'{current_word.rstrip(",.")},'
                    else:
                        yield current_word

        current_input = ' '.join(modify_words(splitted_input))

    print('Input:', input_line, '\nOutput:', current_input, '\n')
```